# How to create deeplinks for android using branch.io

Tags: android, deep-linking, branch.io

We are trying to create some deep links for Android using branch.io but haven't had any success in last 2 days. We would be really glad if we can get some help on how to do it.

Configuration:

Android Manifest:

```
<activity
    android:name=".login.view.DeepLinkActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Login"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
    <intent-filter>
        <data android:scheme="myapp" android:host="open" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Branch.io Dashboard :

Under android redirects section, the value for "Android URI schema" is set to "myapp://"

The link is being generated via branch.io HTTP API. The post request is

```
host: v1/url
request body:

{
    "alias":"xxxx",
    "data":"{\"$fallback_url\":\"www.xxx.com\",\"$android_depplink_path\":\"myapp://open/\"}",
    "branch_key":"key_test_xxxxxxxxxx"
}
```

Whenever we are trying to open this link via email, we are redirected to the fallback URL defined in branch.io dashboard.

Please help us get this configuration right.

Comment: what you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: We are trying to generate deep links for our android application using the branch.io APIs that we are already using for our desktop and mobile websites. The link would be sent to the user via SMS, and if the application is installed on the phone, then the application should pop up; Otherwise, the link should be opened in default mobile browser

Comment: you can do same without branch.io

Comment: hmm. thanks for the advice but we are already using branch.io for web/mWeb and we would be better off with branch.io in this particular case

Comment: Alex from Branch here: it looks like you have a parameter typo — `$android_depplink_path` should be `$android_deeplink_path` and you don't need the URI scheme there...just the path itself. **However** that shouldn't be causing this behavior. Does the link only not work when opened via email? To debug further, we really need an example of an actual link that isn't working correctly. If you don't want to post that here, feel free to [submit a ticket to the Branch integrations team](https://support.branch.io/support/tickets/new)

Answer (score 1):

You need to override `onStart` method of your launcher `Activity` and handle the redirection according to data passed from intent.

**STEP 1**: Generate Deep links using https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/creating-links/apps/android/#generate-the-link

**STEP 2** : Handle the intent and take to desired activity 
https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/deep-link-routing/guide/android/#building-a-custom-deep-link-routing-method

Don't forget to add `android:launchMode="singleTop"` in `Activity` Manifest to have only one instance at a time. 
you can also handle this using `intent.addFlag()` passing `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT` and `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`. Hope this helps.

Comment: How can we genarate deeplink from inside the app. Suppose i have copy option , and on click of that i want to generate deeplink whcih can be shared to others.

Comment: @stackLearner You can use android SDK of branch if you are creating lots of deeplinks in your app. https://help.branch.io/developers-hub/docs/android-basic-integration .
If the usages is not that high, use their REST APIs. https://help.branch.io/developers-hub/docs/deep-linking-api